# iPhone APP to connect to a website without browser bars

Tags: iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

I need to create an APP and all I know is web coding for mobile devices.
Nor do I have a Apple Computer to write the code.
What is the code to display a loading screen and then load in a mobile themed website without the url bar and the bookmark bar?
Is there a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the head of your HTML:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

It will only affect users who add the page to their home screen, though.

For the splash screen:

Your startup image must be 320x460 pixels.

Further details at: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: Btw, do web apps support retina splash screens?

Comment: Can you submit a website with this meta tag to the app store the same way you do a programmed app?

Comment: No. For that you'd need something like PhoneGap.